# Transparent BackColor For Pie Chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, charts

I have added a *Chart* control to my form. When I change its type to a Pie Chart, the `BackColor` remains white. How can I change this color to transparent or at least a color that I want?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so hard because is it so simple:

The `Chart` itself:

```
chart1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

The `ChartArea` of your Pie:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Assuming you have only one, otherwise adapt the index..!

To make it complete here is the (not exactly surprising) code for the `Legend`:

```
chart1.Legends[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

And of course you could choose any other color.

I'm not sure how the Pie Chart type would make a difference. It certainly doesn't make it here..